# Trying to build an ensemble in Keras. Getting a graph disconnected error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ensemble-learning

```python
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py

# sq_model.save_weights('sq_model_weights.h5')
# res_model.save_weights('res_model_weights.h5')
# model.save('my_model.h5')

# dense_model.save_weights('dense_model_v3_weights.h5')

sq_model.load_weights('sq_model_weights.h5')
res_model.load_weights('res_model_weights.h5')
dense_model.load_weights('dense_model_v2_weights.h5')


models = [sq_model, res_model, dense_model]


model_input = Input((3,32,32))

def ensemble(models, model_input):

    outputs = [model.outputs[0] for model in models]
    y = Average()(outputs)

    model = Model(inputs = model_input, outputs = y, name='ensemble')

    return model


ensemble_model = ensemble(models,model_input)
```

I am getting the following error when I run the above code:

RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(?, 3, 32, 32), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Answer (score 3):

You have three models, each of them with a separate input. In your call to

```
model = Model(inputs = model_input, outputs = y, name='ensemble')
```

you specify a new Model. Its input should be your `model_input`, and the outputs should be your averaged outputs.

But you forgot to actually connect your three models to your input. So you have a disconnected model containing the loose input layer `model_input` and the ensemble, with each of the three models contained in the ensemble waiting for an input on its own input layer (so 4 input layers in total).

Changing

```
outputs = [model.outputs[0] for model in models]
```

to

```
outputs = [model(model_inputs) for model in models]
```

should do the trick. It calls each of the models on `model_input` and gives the corresponding outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
outputs = [model.outputs[0] for model in models]
```

to

```
outputs = [model(model_input) for model in models]
```

worked for me

Comment: This is a comment to the previous answer rather than an answer by itself.